# how to count true checkboxes in a word form?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I have 5 checkboxes in a Word form (.dotm). Each time a checkbox = true, a result box will increase by 15 (for € 15 ..) and will decrease by 15 if the checkbox = false.

I wrote that for the moment but, the result stay at 15 even if I pass checkbox=false. The problem I encounter is that my formfield object doesn't change directly following the change of state of the checkbox to 0 or 15, I have an offset, the state changes only after clicking on another checkbox.

```
Sub totalWeek()

    Dim monday As CheckBox
    Dim summary As FormField

    Set monday = ActiveDocument.FormFields("CaseACocher8").CheckBox
    Set summary = ActiveDocument.FormFields("totalSemaine")

    If monday.Value = True Then
    summary.Result = 15
    Else: summary.Result = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the described problem. The textbox is 15 if the checkbox is checked; 0 if it's not. Note that I'm assuming forms protection is activated and that these are, indeed, form fields (since you don't report errors, the latter is likely). You might need to check that the field *names* are correct if nothing is changing and that no fields are *locked*. If you're still having problems you need to provide more information that can help us reproduce the environment, the document, etc.

Comment: Hello, the problem I encounter is that my formfield object doesn't change directly following the change of state of the checkbox to 0 or 15, I have an offset, the state changes only after clicking on another checkbox. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Any actions associated with form fields only execute when the form field is *exited* or *entered*. This is true for performing calculations as well as executing macro code associated with a form field ("On Exit" and "On Enter" macros).

It is *not possible* to see a change of state in another form field when performing an action in one form field (clicking on a checkbox). It is ***always*** necessary to first exit the form field / enter another form field.

There is no way around this, no trick, no "hack".

ActiveX controls do have the capability requested, but as they are not designed for the document surface they do have other drawbacks.